# How do I set the FCKEditor to be readonly?

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor, readonly

I am using FCKEditor ASP.NET control 2.65 in my WebForms application.  How can I set it to be readonly (preferably from the serverside)?

I am not seeing either Enabled or Readonly properties.

Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrap the control in your own control.
2. Publish an Enabled property on your control.
3. Publish a Value property. Manage the state for both of these properties yourself.
4. If Enabled = true at the time of render, then delegate to the underlying FCKEditor control.
5. Otherwise, take the Value and simply render it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.saulmade.nl/FCKeditor/FCKSnippets.php#demoAnchor) is I think the answer for your problem

Comment: Uh, that's not a read only FCKEditor as I was able to edit the rich text easily.

Comment: The website is currently offline.