# Readonly FCKEditor

Tags: readonly, fckeditor

Just to clarify: It means text input must not be possible.

I have tried a lot of things I found in internet but nothing works:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('fckFrame');
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.body.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
doc.body.contentEditable='false'; 
doc.designMode='off';
doc.body.disabled=true;
```

This is executed, it finds everything and throws no errors, but I'm still able to type text in the editor :/

I tried putting the code once in function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editorInstance ) {} in my HTML page, and also in fckeditor.js in a function I call after the editor was created. Both cases run without problems, but I still can type.

I also put attributes contenteditable="false" disabled="true" in body tag of the editor's iframe using firebug. But no effect, i still can type.

I even found this demo, which if I'm not understanding wrong claims to make readonly work, but I can also type there

http://www.saulmade.nl/FCKeditor/FCKSnippets.php#demoAnchor

I'm using the last version of FCKEditor (FCKeditor 2.6.6) and can't change it.

Any kind of solution - official, workaround or tricks are welcome as long as it works!

Thanks

Comment: Does this need to be a client-side option? Otherwise, a potential solution is posted with this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069886/how-do-i-set-the-fckeditor-to-be-readonly

Comment: It has to be clientside. Anyways, isn't the serverside solutions not being translated to clientside code in some way?

Comment: Not in a way that you could turn it on and off. It basically says to swap out the control on the server-side and use the content in the new control.

Comment: There is a lot of discussion about this on their site, check out: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15659 for example.

Comment: Well, the server solution actually works for me (I'm using Flex and HTML component). I use 2 different components depending of editable state. When user wants to switch, I replace the component. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Mind if I move that comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the information on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069886/how-do-i-set-the-fckeditor-to-be-readonly) would solve your problem if you're happy to use a server-side solution.

It basically says to swap out the control on the server-side and use the content in the new control.